# Почтовые формы в html

Tags: html, php

Как сделать, чтоб заказ через почтовые формы в html приходил мне на e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

Если вкратце:
На сайте добавить форму с нужными полями:

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="adress" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

На странице send.php ловить событие от формы, например так:

```
if($_SERVER['METHOD'] == 'post' && isset($_POST['send']))
```

и отправлять письмо с помошью mail()

Answer (score 0):

Ну на чистом HTML не получиться , а если использовать например PHP то с помощью функции SendMail, ищеться в поисковике легко.